# Cordova Electron import problem ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Tags: cordova, electron

I installed electron in a cordova project but when I run `cordova run electron --nobuild` all the js and css files they give me ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND in console

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
topcoat-mobile-light.css:1 
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND 
angular-carousel.min.css:1 
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
font-awesome.min.css:1 
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
all.min.css:1 
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
old-styles.css:1    
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
styles.css:1 
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
angular.min.js:1 
.....
```

I import its like this:

```
<html lang="en">  
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
<link href="topcoat/css/topcoat-mobile-light.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/angular-carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/all.min.css">
...
```

This happens for all imports.

This is the structure of my www folder:
[image]

How can I do?

Comment: try absolute path /css ...

Comment: I try but not work

Comment: what version of cordova election?